# Cosmos DB REST API not returning data for cross partition query for newly created collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-rest-api

I've been using the Cosmos DB REST API to query collections, and I've encountered an issue with a specific query when the cross partition is set to true. Strangely, the query works for older collections but not for the ones created in the past 5-6 months. All collections were created using the same scripts.

The only recent change we made to our Cosmos DB is enabling AAD-only authentication. Consequently, our script now retrieves the AAD token instead of the master key. Could this change be affecting the query's behavior in the new collections?

Note : Same query works for both old and new collection in azure cosmos data explorer https://cosmos.azure.com/?feature.enableAadDataPlane=true

Here's a screenshot of postman REST API call

Headers :
[image]

Request and Response :
[image]

Comment: can you also pass x-ms-continuation?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#queries-that-cannot-be-served-by-gateway

Comment: @Sajeetharan what value I should set for that header when I am calling it for first time?  I my case I don't really want to paginate through all records. My requirement is to check if there is any records matching my filter condition. Actually I am using "x-ms-max-item-count"="1" so I am just trying to fetch single record.

Comment: Are you getting any Continuation Token ( x-ms-continuation) in the Response Headers?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta  Continuation token in the response header is null
x-ms-continuation: {"token":null,"range":{"min":"05C1B9CD673390","max":"05C1C9CD673390"}}

Comment: That is not null, that has a value, a null value would be truly an empty value or the header not present, you are showing something that has range and other characters. Please consume it and send it in the next request -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination#continuation-tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing queries, check the `x-ms-continuation` header in the response.

If the header is present and has some value (based on the comments it's `{"token":null,"range":{"min":"05C1B9CD673390","max":"05C1C9CD673390"}}`), then you need to use it on a next request to keep consuming the query results.

Queries can have empty pages, particularly cross-partition ones.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination#continuation-tokens

Comment: Yes you are right. I got confused with "token": null so I didn't try to pass the continuation token assuming that it is null. I had raised the support ticket with Microsoft  as well and even they suggested the same and it worked. 

Thanks for your time.